# Arrancar un vbs desde los recursos

Tags: c#

Mi pregunta es simple ¿seria posible arrancar un `vbs` desde los recursos usando `process start` y leyendo el `manifest` del archivo? ¿O la única manera posible es por medio es escribiendo en disco?

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() .GetManifestResourceStream("script.vbs"))
```

Y luego arrancarlo usando `process start`:

```
Process.Start(cscript.exe Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() .GetManifestResourceStream("script.vbs")))
```

Comment: Me temo que debes escribirlo en disco.

Comment: Como te menciona @Pikoh creo que debes hacerlo mediante el disco puede hacer algo como esto: `Process.Start("script.exe", "C:\\tuscript.vbs");`, mira un link interesante aquí: [¿Cómo puedo extraer un archivo de un recurso incrustado y guardarlo en el disco?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34664553/8933039) (Traducir del Ingles)